# Should we use READ transaction?

Tags: opendaylight

A few years ago I read ODL recommendation not to use READ operation but instead use Data Change Listener or some of its variation. Is it still valid recommendation?
Looking at the ODL code, I got impression that each transaction commit is applied to “In Memory Data Store” immediately during the commit simultaneously with sending notification to the listener. Is it correct?
Why in this case, reading is not as efficient as using the notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you read this recommendation? It depends on your use case. Using a data tree change listener (DTCL) with your own cache is going to have faster access than issuing a read operation, especially in a clustered environment if the shard leader is remote. However maintaining your own cache via a DTCL is eventually consistent, meaning your cache may not have up-to-date data. This has to be considered for the use case. If you need strong consistency, then you must use read operations.

Comment: Actually, I am surprised by such solution. Updating the memory data store with each commit is not for free.  If even it does not affect CPU performance directly it definitely affects the memory consumption. The notifications are processed asynchronously. Each of them contains the data tree before and after.  Eventually, it affects CPU by increasing the time needed to GC.
I would prefer if the data store were updated in batch mode basing on the number of transactions and/or time iterval.